# Tax on product issue (inclu = exclu) but calculated on freigt charges

Tags: vat

I have a problem with the tax culation in my system. I haven been searching since several days but I can not find where the issue lays. I have even tried by putting my product on tax-rate shipping, ...

[image: shopping basket]

Comment: can you please detail what are your settings for tax calculation and include them in your question?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the problem. I have deleted all the products and loaded them again and from that moment the vat calculation was correct on the products.